# Where to perform action with update in React + React Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Let's say I have a music component connected to the "play" prop in the redux store.

When "play" is updated, I would like to update the playback status (play, pause, etc) accordingly. However, this does not influence how the component looks. So I'm wondering where to perform the update actions?

I was using componentWillReceiveProps to control the playback when the prop is updated, it works but apparently that is incorrect use according to the React team, and the method will be deprecated.

Comment: When you update a piece of state that isn't used by any container component, nothing will happen.

Comment: You can just use normal props and update inside the actions and reducers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dispatch an action with the selected playback status within the onClick function that is passed through a reducer and updates the state of the store. The component, if connected properly to the store using the connect function in the react-redux library, will automatically update the rendering of the component.

Comment: But where exactly would I control the media? I don't want the component to re-render because nothing visual changes.

Comment: In this case, you will not avoid a re-render of the component, because the state is changing whether visual or not. 

That being said, if for some reason, you are only wanting to change a value in the database or some external variable, then you may call a function directly that will not cause a re-render. I don't see how this would be helpful though since I would think the component would want to know the current state.

Comment: Where would I call the function following a state update without causing a re-render?

Comment: Within the React component lifecycle, shouldComponentUpdate is called before the render method. If false is returned from this function, then a re-render won't occur.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I'm just confused about what the best practice would be. If I have a music component, I would want to keep the playback control within that component, and I don't want the component to re-render when I'm simply changing the playback (assuming nothing visual changes).

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but you are updating the 'state' of the component, not visually but otherwise. 

Down the line, I would even say that you may have a button icon to toggle between triangle and two lines which at that point, the 'visual' state would change.

Comment: So is it still good practice to keep the playback status in the state? I don't know where else to store it.

Comment: Yes, it is! State reigns supreme in an application.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the answer.